# tikz-feynman: complex diagram being drawn partially

Tags: tikz-feynman

I'm trying to reproduce this diagram from an article:

[image]

I achieved this:

[image]

As you can see, the lines after the loop are not being drawn, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
    
        \vertex (a1) {\(\overline b\)};
        \vertex[right=1.5cm of a1] (a2);
        \vertex[right=1cm of a2] (a3);
        \vertex[right=1.5cm of a3] (a4) {\(\overline s\)};
        \vertex[below=2em of a1] (b1) {\(u\)};
        \vertex[below=2em of a4] (b2) {\(u\)};
        \vertex at ($(a2)!0.5!(a3)!0.5cm!90:(a3)$) (d);
        
        \vertex[above=1cm of d] (c1);
        \vertex[above right=1cm of c1] (c2) {$l$};
        \vertex[above left=1cm of c1] (c3) {$\overline{l}$};
        
        \diagram* {
        (a4) -- [fermion] (a3) -- [charged boson, edge label=$W^+$] (a2) -- [anti fermion] (a1),
        (b1) -- [fermion] (b2),
        (a2) -- [fermion, quarter left] (d) -- [fermion, quarter left] (a3),
        };
        
        (d) -- [photon] (c1);
        (c1) -- [fermion] (c2);
        (c1) -- [anti fermion] (c3);
        
    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (b1.south west) -- (a1.north west)
    node [pos=0.5, left] {\(B^{+}\)};
    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (a4.north east) -- (b2.south east)
    node [pos=0.5, right] {\(K^+\)};
    
    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I haven't introduced the `$\overline{u},\overline{c},\overline{t}$` label yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted the example from the manual to your requirements and change of using a charged W+ boson. Basically my changes are indicated:

- renaming labels or node `content`
- removing `in/out` options to achieve straight lines
- moving `vertex c2` a little
- left some minor nuances with `uct`
- introduced `anti`-particles for consistency
- leave it up to you to "mirror" the diagram horizontally
- neglected the `figure`-environment, as it's easy to add

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex                             (a1) {\(\overline b\)};
    \vertex[right=1.5cm of a1]          (a2);
    \vertex[right=1cm of a2]            (a3);
    \vertex[right=1.5cm of a3]          (a4) {\(\overline s\)};% <<
    \vertex[below=2em of a1]            (b1) {\(u\)};% <<
    \vertex[below=2em of a4]            (b2) {\(u\)};% <<
    
    %% See section 13.5 of PGF/TikZ manual
    \vertex at ($(a2)!0.5!(a3)!0.7cm!90:(a3)$) (d);% <<
    
    %% Equivalent way to obtain (d):
    % \vertex at ($(b2)!0.5!(b3) + (0, -0.5cm)$) (d);
    \vertex[above=of a4]                    (c1) {\(l^{-}\)};% <<
    \vertex[above=2em of c1]                (c3) {\(l^{+}\)};% <<
    \vertex at ($(c1)!0.5!(c3) - (2.3cm, 0)$) (c2);
    
    \diagram* {% <<
        (a4) -- [fermion] (a3) -- [charged boson, edge label=$W^+$](a2) -- [fermion] (a1),
        (b1) -- [fermion] (b2),
        (c3) -- [fermion] (c2) -- [fermion] (c1),
        (a2) -- [anti fermion, quarter left, edge label=\(uct\)] (d) -- [anti fermion, quarter left] (a3),
        (d) -- [boson, edge label=\(\gamma / Z^{0}\)] (c2),
    };
    
    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (b1.south west) 
            -- (a1.north west) node [pos=0.5, left] {\(B^{+}\)};
% << deleted 1 draw statement
    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (a4.north east)
            -- (b2.south east) node [pos=0.5, right] {\(K^{+}\)};% <<
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```